# calculate the rate parameter: exponential distribution

Tags: c++, distribution, probability-density

I have a set of values which follows [exponential distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution). Now, I want to calculate the rate parameter alpha. Can anybody help me how to calculate it (I am using c++ to code it)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you **know** these values are from an exponential distribution, then you can calculate the maximum likelihood of λ (lambda, not alpha) as the average of `1 / value` for each of these values (because the mean of the exponential distribution is `1 / λ`). this is a statistical calculation, since you are trying to assess a parameter through observation.